# Connecting, joining or merging Substitution Permutation layer

Tags: symmetric, permutation, substitution-cipher, spn

I am trying to identify how the **SP Network** is constructed. I am looking for plausible solutions that help to connect these layers together and what are the ways that exist in literature other than **Kam and Davida** and **The wide trail strategy of AES** that can help in creation of a secure SP network.